# COUNTIF with multiple criteria and list

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

I need to count the number of cells in which 'CRITERIA 1' is satisfied, 'CRITERIA 2' is satisfied and 'CRITERIA 3' falls within the set of values contained in column E.

I am currently using the following formula:

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(A2:A11,"TRUE",B2:B11,"TRUE",C2:C11,{"2","4","6","9","10"}))
```

But in my real table, the list of data within 'CRITERIA 3' is longer and more complicated and I would prefer to reference the cells in column E rather than the specific data, i.e. something like:

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(A2:A11,"TRUE",B2:B11,"TRUE",C2:C11,{"E2:E6"}))
```

Please note that the data contained in this example is different to the data in my real table. The real table is considerably longer and more complex than this table.

Any suggestions?

[image: Example]

Comment: Close `=SUM(COUNTIFS(A2:A11,"TRUE",B2:B11,"TRUE",C2:C11,E2:E6))`  It is an array formula, so Ctrl-Shift-Enter to confirm instead of Enter.  The range itself is the array, no need for the `{""}`.

Comment: Yes of course, that makes sense - silly of me to have missed it. Thank you. Put that as an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Decided to put my comment as an answer so I can show a picture that it works:

You are close.  The Range is an array so no need for the `{""}` wrapper

Just use:

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(A2:A11,"TRUE",B2:B11,"TRUE",C2:C11,E2:E6))
```

This is an array formula and must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could try SUMPRODUCT

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A11="TRUE")*(B2:B11="TRUE")*(E2:E6="2"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `COUNTIFS` the only way I'd know of to check a value is in a list is to create a dummy column that has that check and make that column Criteria3 instead of the actual value.

Going from your example, you'd drop in the following formula in Column D (set text to white so the workbook doesn't look ugly):
`=IF(COUNTIF(E$2:E$6, C2)>0, 1, "")`

Then your Criteria3 updates such that you have:
`=SUM(COUNIFS(A2:A11, "TRUE", B2:B11, "TRUE", D2:D11, 1))`

If that's non-ideal, the only other way I can think of would be to use a macro to get that `SUM` for you.